# filter issue in autocomplete in android using AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android

I make a simple demo of auto complete .I take array of string in which there is 2250 entries with **Name and code** like that example **"Alexandra Palace-(AAP)",** first name is given and the it code inside the bracket.my issue is I need to filter this using code not by name .In other word if i type anything in input field it filter with starting characters of element mean  name I need to filter with code which is inside the bracket.

here is my code..

package com.firstgroup.global;

```
public class GlobalList {

    public static String[] stationList={

        "MNCRLWY-(LWY)",
        "Lympstone Commando-(LYC)",
        "Lydney-(LYD)",
        "Lye-(LYE)",
        "Lympstone Village-(LYM)",
        "Lymington Pier-(LYP)",
        "Lymington Town-(LYT)",
        "Lazonby & Kirkoswald-(LZB)",
        "Leeds, Whitehall (Bus)-(LZZ)",
        "Macclesfield-(MAC)",
        "Maghull-(MAG)",
        "Maidenhead-(MAI)",
        "Malden Manor-(MAL)",
        "Manchester Piccadilly-(MAN)",
        "Martins Heron-(MAO)",
        "Margate-(MAR)",
        "Manors-(MAS)",
        "Matlock-(MAT)",
        "Mauldeth Road-(MAU)",
        "Mallow-(MAW)",
        "Maxwell Park-(MAX)",
        "Maybole-(MAY)",
        "Millbrook (Hampshire)-(MBK)",
        "Middlesbrough-(MBR)",
        "Moulsecoomb-(MCB)",
        "Metro Centre-(MCE)",
        "March-(MCH)",
        "Marne La Vallee-(MCK)",
        "Morecambe-(MCM)",
        "Machynlleth-(MCN)",
        "Manchester Oxford Road-(MCO)",
        "Manchester Victoria-(MCV)",
        "Maidstone Barracks-(MDB)",
        "Maidstone East-(MDE)",
        "Midgham-(MDG)",
        "Middlewood-(MDL)",
        "Maiden Newton-(MDN)",
        "Morden South-(MDS)",
        "Maidstone West-(MDW)",
        "MAERDY-(MDY)",
        "Meols Cop-(MEC)",
        "Meldreth-(MEL)",
        "Menheniot-(MEN)",
        "Meols-(MEO)",
        "Meopham-(MEP)",
        "Merthyr Tydfil-(MER)",
        "Melton-(MES)",
        "Merthyr Vale-(MEV)",
        "Maesteg (Ewenny Road)-(MEW)",
        "Mexborough-(MEX)",
        "Merryton-(MEY)",
        "Morfa Mawddach-(MFA)",
        "Minffordd-(MFD)",
        "Minffordd-(MFF)",
        "Milford Haven-(MFH)",
        "Mount Florida-(MFL)",
        "Mansfield-(MFT)",
        "Metheringham-(MGM)",
        "Marston Green-(MGN)",
        "Minehead-(MHD)",
        "Merstham-(MHM)",
        "Market Harborough-(MHR)",
        "Meadowhall-(MHS)",
        "Manchester Airport-(MIA)",
        "Micheldever-(MIC)",
        "Millfield (T & W Metro)-(MIF)",
        "Mills Hill-(MIH)",
        "Mitcham Junction-(MIJ)",
        "Micklefield-(MIK)",
        "Mill Hill Broadway-(MIL)",
        "Moreton-in-Marsh-(MIM)",
        "Milliken Park-(MIN)",
        "Mirfield-(MIR)",
        "Mistley-(MIS)",
        "Milton Keynes Central-(MKC)",
        "Melksham-(MKM)",
        "Market Rasen-(MKR)",
        "Marks Tey-(MKT)",
        "Millbrook (Bedfordshire)-(MLB)",
        "Mouldsworth-(MLD)",
        "Milford (Surrey)-(MLF)",
        "Mallaig-(MLG)",
        "Mill Hill (Lancashire)-(MLH)",
        "Millom-(MLM)",
        "Milngavie-(MLN)",
        "MILESPL-(MLP)",
        "Milnrow-(MLR)",
        "Melrose (Bus)-(MLS)",
        "Malton-(MLT)",
        "Marlow-(MLW)",
        "Morley-(MLY)",
        "Melton Mowbray-(MMO)",
        "Markinch-(MNC)",
        "Manea-(MNE)",
        "Manningtree-(MNG)",
        "Menston-(MNN)",
        "Manor Park-(MNP)",
        "Manor Road-(MNR)",
        "MINZHBF-(MNZ)",
        "Mobberley-(MOB)",
        "Moorgate-(MOG)",
        "Monifieth-(MON)",


};

}
```

when I type **"lwy"** it will not show **"MNCRLWY-(LWY)",** can you please tell how I will achieve this ?

here is my code..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.select_station);

     autocompleteView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.item_autoComplete);

     STATION_LIST = new String[GlobalList.stationList.length
                                        + GlobalExtendStationList.stationList.length];
                                System.arraycopy(GlobalList.stationList, 0, STATION_LIST, 0,
                                        GlobalList.stationList.length);
                                System.arraycopy(GlobalExtendStationList.stationList, 0,
                                        STATION_LIST, GlobalList.stationList.length,
                                        GlobalExtendStationList.stationList.length);
                                autosuggestAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,STATION_LIST);
                                autocompleteView.setAdapter(autosuggestAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a custom adapter, which implements Filterable and BaseAdapter.You have to override the function getFilter() ..
Here is an example using list.

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Filter myFilter = new Filter() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {

            System.out.println("Constraint " + constraint);
            // has

            if (results.count > 0 && results != null) {
                objects = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults(); // Holds the
                                                            // results of a
                                                            // filtering
                                                            // operation in
                                                            // values

            List<String> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<String>();

            if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<String>(objects); // saves

            }

            /********
             * 
             * If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null returns
             * the mOriginalValues(Original) values else does the Filtering
             * and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)
             * 
             ********/

            Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();

            constraint = (String) constraint
                    .toString().toLowerCase(locale);
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                // set the Original result to return
                results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                results.values = mOriginalValues;
            } else {


                for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                    String name= mOriginalValues.get(i);


                    if (name.toLowerCase(locale).contains(constraint)
                ) {
                        if (!FilteredArrList.contains(model)) {
                            FilteredArrList.add(model);
                        }

                    }
                }
                // set the Filtered result to return
                results.count = FilteredArrList.size();

                results.values = FilteredArrList;

            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //convert object to string
            return "";
        }
    };
    return myFilter;
}
```

Comment: do you want the entire adapter class.?

Comment: we try but not get success http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540448/why-autosuggest-not-display-and-how-to-add-filter-functionalty .please check this